# Is there any project template with integrated user authentication?

Tags: symfony4

I am begging with Symfony so I want to ask. 
Is there any project template with integrated user authentication, registration, roles etc.?
I tried googling it, but everything I can find looks so complicated and it's even without registration.
I am switching from Asp.net core, which allows creating project with all this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any templates. But with a new MakerBundle it should be easy to create a login authentication. Try to follow this Docs. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html . The maker should generate Authentication, routes, controller and views. That would be good start. **Note that you need to complete also this one before!** https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html